# Regexp for first consecutive non whitespace ending with @?

Tags: regular-expressions, query-replace-regexp

I have a mailing list whose lines contain garbage characterized by spaces, like this:

> bar qux foo@mail.com

for which I want to extract `foo@mail.com`. I tried this unsuccessfully:

```
M-x query-replace-regexp RET \(.+\)\([^ ]+\)@ → \2@
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match the longest prefix ending with a space:

```
^\(.* \)
```

Note also that `[^ ]` matches newlines and `@`, so be careful with that.  To interactively enter a regexp matching neither spaces nor newlines, you can type:

<kbd>[</kbd><kbd>^</kbd><kbd>SPC</kbd><kbd>C-q</kbd><kbd>C-j</kbd><kbd>]</kbd>

(n.b. In lisp that's just `"[^ \n]"`).